# Eclipse - Starting Tomcat 7 Server at localhost has encountered a problem

Tags: 13.10, eclipse, tomcat7

I got this error just after getting an Ubuntu error with eclipse and it forced to close the program.

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at
>   localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in
>   another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start
>   this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port
>   number(s).

I got that error even after stopping manually the server

```
$> sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ]

$> sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 status
 * Tomcat servlet engine is not running.
```

What could I do without having to reboot the computer?

**System details**

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
- Tomcat v 7.0.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command to identify any Tomcat process running in the background:

```
ps -ef | grep "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" | grep -v grep
```

You should get a row like this for each running instance:

```
username    26546  5581 71 12:51 ?        00:00:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dcatalina.base=/home/ringo/eclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0 -Dcatalina.home=/home/ringo/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.37 -Dwtp.deploy=/home/ringo/eclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/ringo/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/endorsed -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/ringo/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ringo/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

The second value on the row is the process ID. You can then use the kill command to terminate it, e.g.:

```
kill -9 26546
```

To both find the process and kill it in a single command:

```
ps -ef | grep "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and followed [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065874/1317271) to resolve the issue. In short, shutdown the tomcat service by going to `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin` and then executing `./shutdown.sh` which gave some warning messages(not java exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two server in your eclipse eclipse

If you want to solve this then
1. go to bottom of the eclipse ide click on the server and double click tomcat v8.0 whatever you have after clicking Overvie widow will be appear in this 
check the port and chenge the port numbers

2.If you don't want to change the port number then you have add only one server in your eclipse ide so you have to delete the server from your ide accept one server 
 to delete
   go to window -> prefreneces -> servers -> runtimes environment 
servers will be appear right side add and remove  and etc buttons will be available select the server which you have to remove and click remove button and then ok

finish
Thank you...........